# Getting single document ID in Firebase Cloud Functions (Firestore) with angular

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I wanted to get the id of a single document dynamically with cloud-firestore and angular, but each time the result tells me document not found.

```
   getOneFacture(factureId: string){
    let docId = firebase.firestore().collection('facture').doc(factureId).get()
      .then( doc => {
        if(doc.exists){
          console.log('Document Id => ', doc.id)
          console.log('Document data => ', doc.data())
        }else {
          console.log('Document not found')
        }
      });
    return docId;
  }
```

[image: I wanted to get the id of a single document dynamically with cloud-firestore and angular but each time the result tells me document not found]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you saying your `console.log('Document not found')` gets executed even when the value of `factureId` matches one of the IDs shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes sir. i got git in my console document not found

Comment: Can you edit your question to show: 1) a bigger screenshot where we can also see the collection name? 2) updated code where you `console.log(JSON.stringify(factureId));` and its output?

Comment: What is your factureId?

Answer (score 1):

```
 const db = firebase.firestore().collection('facture').orderBy('today', 'desc');
return db.get().then(
  (snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
      return {
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data()
      };
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: In this project we did not use angular / fire so I returned an object with the fields id, data
suddenly I can retrieve the id of a single document by passing a parameter in my function and it works thanks to all the people who answered

Answer (score 0):

Please refer **[@angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/0f6f2bf83c93a3a475bbfe4f7d37a6aa6fc1d03d/docs/firestore/documents.md)** plugin docs for your reference.